# iText 7 attach to email

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext, attachment, mailmessage

I am trying to attach a PDF generated with iText7 to an email.  The email sends successfully, but the attached PDF is always corrupt and around 15 bytes in size.  According to my reading, this should be easily accomplished with a MemoryStream, but I think I am messing up the "order of operations."

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
string fileName = vm.ClientFirstName + vm.ClientLastName + vm.SubmittedDate.Year + vm.SubmittedDate.Month + vm.SubmittedDate.Day + "referral.pdf";
PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(ms);
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
Document document = new Document(pdf);
PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(iText.IO.Font.Constants.StandardFonts.HELVETICA);
Image img = new Image(ImageDataFactory.Create(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~\\Content\\Images\\banner.png")));
List list = new List().SetSymbolIndent(12).SetListSymbol("").SetFont(font);
document.Add(img);
document.Add(new Paragraph("Radiology Referral").SetFont(font).SetFontSize(24));
document.Add(new Paragraph("VARIOUS BITS OF INFORMATION FROM THE FORM IN STRING FORMAT").SetFont(font));
document.Flush();
writer.Flush();
ms.Position = 0;
var message = new MailMessage("example@example.com", "example@example.com", "PDF Report", "See the attached PDF.");
var attachment = new Attachment(ms, fileName);
message.Attachments.Add(attachment);

//send email...
```

What am I messing up?  If I am doing *everything* wrong, a working example would be fantastic.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't close the `Document` or the `PdfDocument`. The pdf is not completed in the output stream before closing.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add

```
pdf.Close();
```

That will call `pdf.Flush()` which will write to the underlying stream.